# android arrayAdapter with autocomletetextview not working with List<...>

Tags: android

**1) The code below : getView does not get called when I type in autocompletetextview. Watch out the list in the fragment and the adapter class extending List**

```
   public class SigninFragment extends Fragment {
        private List<Test> list= null;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Test tes= new Test ();
    tes.setId(1);
    tes.setDesc("descabc");
    list= new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(prof);

    tesListAdapter =
            new TesListAdapter(
                    rootView.getContext()
                    ,R.layout.list_row_adapter
                    ,list);

    autocompletetextview.setThreshold(3);
    autocompletetextview.setAdapter(tesListAdapter );
```

My Adapter Class :

```
public class ProfissoesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Test> { **<==HERE**
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int resource;

public TesListAdapter(Context activity, int resource, List<Test> listaProf) **<==HERE**{

    super(activity, resource, listaProf);
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
```

...

**2) The code below : YES... getView() does get called when I type in autocompletetextview. watch out in the fragment the String[] array and the adapter exteding ArrayAdapter**

```
   public class SigninFragment extends Fragment {
        private List<Test> list= null;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


    String[] list =  {"abcde","bbbbbb","bbbakaka","ccccccc","dddddd"};

    tesListAdapter =
            new TesListAdapter(
                    rootView.getContext()
                    ,R.layout.list_row_adapter
                    ,list);

    autocompletetextview.setThreshold(3);
    autocompletetextview.setAdapter(tesListAdapter );
```

My Adapter Class :

```
public class ProfissoesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {  **<==HERE**
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int resource;

public TesListAdapter(Context activity, int resource, String[] listaProf) {  **<==HERE**

    super(activity, resource, listaProf);
    this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
```

...

**QUESTION:** Why the 1) option does not call my getView in the adapter class when I type matching value in the autocomplete textview ? thx

Comment: thats it. I have fixed this days ago and you are right. please respond it outside this comment box so I can check your answer. thx

Comment: This wasn't the reason for the comment on the other question?

Comment: nop. in the other question I have a fragment class and a custom adapter. When I debugg the adapter , its not able to find the nested elements inside RelativeLayout

Comment: @Luksprog would you please see my question if possible http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32722886/fragment-with-custom-arrayadapter-and-layout-with-multiple-elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case getView() doesn't get called because it doesn't match what you type in the autocomplete widget. The problem is that, when used with a custom class(not String/CharSequence), ArrayAdapter gets the data by calling toString() on the data object(in your case the Test's toString() method).

If you haven't overridden that method to return something meaningful(like the value set with setDesc()) it will return something like this Test@(somenumbershere) which will not match what you type as a filter. So, the key is to provide a proper toString() method.