# fragment with custom arrayadapter and layout with multiple elements

Tags: android

**My layout named main_layout** has a RelativeLayout with at least two elements like Textview and Imageview inside it.

```
public class SigninFragment extends Fragment {
            private List<Test> list= null;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    Test tes= new Test ();
    tes.setId(1);
    tes.setDesc("descabc");
    list= new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(prof);

    tesListAdapter =
            new TesListAdapter(
                    rootView.getContext()
                    ,R.layout.list_row_adapter
                    ,list);

    autocompletetextview.setThreshold(3);
    autocompletetextview.setAdapter(tesListAdapter );
```

My Adapter Class :

```
public class ProfissoesListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Test> { 
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int resource;
private Context context;

public TesListAdapter(Context activity, int resource, List<Test> listaProf) {

super(activity, resource, listaProf);
this.resource = resource;
this.context = context;
```

}

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_layout, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.idProfissao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
            //holder.descProfissao = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textDescProf);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        Test item = getItem(position);
        holder.idProfissao.setText(item.getId_prof());  **<=== BUG HERE**

        return convertView;
    }
```

Debugging adapter code I got in the line holder.idProfissao.setText(item.getId_prof()); Resource id cannot be found....

Comment: find that id in your xml? check if it exists or not. otherwise clean project and run

Comment: it exists. I cleaned up project but with no results...

Comment: you are getting error her: item.getId_prof(). are you sure your get method returns the correct value?

Comment: yep. its returning the correct value. Ive inspected it.  Error : android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method setText() of the TextView class it's overloaded to either use a String or an integer representing an id in the form of R.string.some_text. If item.getId_prof() doesn't return an id then you need to make it a String before setting it as text:

```
 holder.idProfissao.setText("" + item.getId_prof());
```

Comment: but its returning a valid id. I hardcoded it only for tests : Test tes= new Test ();
    tes.setId(1);
    tes.setDesc("descabc");

Comment: @Al2x Does `getId_prof()` return an id in the form of `R.string.name_of_string`(this id will correspond to a string declared in the `values/strings.xml` file)? If you just return an arbitrary integer then you need to make it a string before passing it to the setText() method. Also check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: TY for your time. you are totally right. How could I forget a encapsulated detail like this.